ASP.NET Core flow slow before reaching action
We've a new app using ASP.NET Core 8.0.11.
We noticed some calls were quite slow (seconds instead of milliseconds).
According to AppInsight we see there is one second between request start and reaching the controller.
When we compare the log between a slow request and a normal request all the steps are exactly the same but in the slow requests some really basic steps take 300ms. When you cumulate all slow steps we loose a lot of time.
Here is a print of the traces generating by ASP.NET Core in AppInsight.

It seems it's the first request after inactivity but it's not clear. Sometimes it happens after 10 minutes of inactivity sometimes it does not happen after 30 minutes of inactivity.
For the routing we're using the classic annotations.
It worth mentioning our controllers are in a separated DLL than the main one.
We do not have special middleware (except health check, swagger, ...).
No filter except the invalidmodelstate one.
The whole stuff is deployed in AKS.
No CPU throttling.
No sleep mode, it's still running and waiting for a request.
It's not the full trace until our logs but you get the idea.
I cannot show the code but I just want to see if it rings a bell.
